# iOS - function JSONObjectWithData has issue with JSON injection

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, nsdictionary

In my project, I have some Util functions convert NSData to NSDictionary or NSArray use NSJSONSerialization https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsjsonserialization/1415493-jsonobjectwithdata?language=objc

Example:

```
+ (NSDictionary *) jsonToDictionary: (NSData *)jsonResult mutableContainer:(BOOL)mutContainer mutableString:(BOOL)mutString failBlock:(void(^)(NSError *)) failBlock {
    NSError *error;
    NSDictionary *result = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonResult options:(kNilOptions) || (mutContainer ? NSJSONReadingMutableContainers:kNilOptions) || (mutString ? NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves: kNilOptions) error:&error];
    if (error) {
        if (failBlock) {
            failBlock (error);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

But when this project use Penetration Test from partner. They said that it has **JSON injection**.

- **Description**

JavaScript Object Notation or JSON is an open-standard file format that uses human-readable text to transmit data objects consisting of attribute–value pairs and array data types.

- **Observation**

During assessment, it was observed that application writes unvalidated input into JSON.

- **Statement**

JSON injection occurs when data enters the program from untrusted sources. This call could allow an attacker to inject arbitrary elements or attributes into the JSON entity. Succesful exploitation may potentially lead to denial of service or compromise of the mobile application.

- **Recommendation**

When writing user supplied data to JSON some guidelines should be followed:

1. Don't create JSON attributes whose names are derived from user input.
2. Ensure that all serialization to JSON is performed using a safe serialization function e.g. NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject that delimits untrusted data within single or double quotes and escapes any special characters.

> How can I pass the pentation-test-rules of JSON injection but still
>   able to maintain the correct functionality of this function

Comment: I don't think there is anything inherently insecure in your code snippet. You could perform some validation but that will not stop an attacker who injects valid elements. So, you need to be confident that it is reasonable to trust the source of `jsonResult` in the context of the level of risk in your domain and your upstream technical controls. For example, if the data comes from the network, are you using TLS and certificate pinning?

Comment: Sure. I also encrypted string and json files. So i think the only way is that check code use this functions and explain with my colleague.